# IText5 - large memory usage while creating 10000 page PDF using the same content and SmartPdfCopy

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to generate 10000 pages PDF using single template PDF with `AcroForm`  that I am filling with values during the process.

My problem is, that I am hitting `OOME`, and the app itself consumes 4GB. How can i lower memory consumption?

How I create my content:

```
public PDFBuilderItext5(InputStream templateSource) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        templateBytes = readTemplateToBytes(templateSource);
//      output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("z:\\itext\\buff.pdf"));
        document = new Document();
        copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, output);
        document.open();
    }
```

this is done in loop:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream tempOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templateBytes);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, tempOut);
        try {
            AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
//          fields.setGenerateAppearances(true);
            Set<String> fieldNames = fields.getFields().keySet();
            FieldValueBuilder fb = new FieldValueBuilder(t);
            for (String fn : fieldNames) {
                String label = fields.getField(fn);
                String value = fb.valueFor(label);
                fields.setField(fn, value,value);
            }
            stamper.setFormFlattening(true);

        } finally {
            stamper.close();
            reader.close();
        }
        append(tempOut.toByteArray());

private synchronized void append(byte[] pdfContent) throws DocumentException, IOException{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfContent);
    copy.addDocument(reader);
    reader.close();
    notFlushedPagesCount++;
    if(notFlushedPagesCount>=FLUSH_INTERVAL){
        copy.flush();
        System.out.println("Flushed copy");
        notFlushedPagesCount=0;
    }
}
```

I have feeling that I am not releasing some resources somewhere because of this:

[image]

Comment: You use a `PdfSmartCopy`. To be *smart* the `PdfSmartCopy` instance needs to keep information on already written information. Thus, a certain memory footprint is to be expected. Whether or not it is too large, can only be analyzed if you provide enough data to reproduce your situation.

Comment: @mkl yes I understand that, but still sound like to much of consumption. Template has 10 input fields, Every input is a string between 20-40 chars of lenght. I looks like PdfSmartCopy is not reusing the "template" to me despite the fact, that generated PDF is indeed approx 20mb large. Maybe it has something to do with template itself. Maybe "resuable elements aggregation" is done on close not on while adding new pages?

Comment: Your code flattens the form elements into the page content. This probably prevents the contents of the resulting pages to be identical and, therefore, a single content to be re-used as template.

Comment: Hmm interesting, as this could make sense. How come that PDF on the other hand is only 26mb large while template itself is about 1.5MB - clearly reused elements. I will most probably move to IText7, it generates smaller pdfs and is faster but consumes not much less memory.

Comment: *"How come that PDF on the other hand is only 26mb large while template itself is about 1.5MB - clearly reused elements."* Probably resources are re-used, merely not the page content stream as such. A template of 1.5MB sounds like quite some resources (bitmap images, fonts, ...).

Comment: @mkl sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You never "free" the reader.

For instance:

```
private synchronized void append(byte[] pdfContent)
    throws DocumentException, IOException{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfContent);
    copy.addDocument(reader);
    copy.freeReader(reader);
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to get answer from you Bruno, thank you, but this does not fix the issue. Memory consumption is constantly growing. And it is approx. 2gb after 3000 iterations. What else can I do? In production there will be cap of 1000 pages max, but shouldnt it work with 10 000 as well?

Comment: 8000 iterations and app is choking, using 3.8GB of heap. Template PDF has 10 input fields, text only.

Comment: Well, it is *normal* that memory is building up, because `PdfSmartCopy` keeps a hash of every object that is encountered. If it detects two identical hashes, it knows that the object can be reused. The more objects your process encounters, the more memory you need. You could work around this, by bundling the copy process. For instance: instead of trying to bundle 10,000 pages once, bundle 1,000 pages 10 times, then bundle the 10 documents with 1,000 pages into a document of 10,000 pages.

Comment: It also depends on which version of iText 5 you are using. I remember that we fixed a `PdfSmartCopy` problem for a customer last year. If you are a customer, you could get more info about that fix. (I no longer do customer support, so I can't look it up right now.)

Comment: I understand but its ounds like a bug to me, as I am "reusing" the same template over, and over, so SmartCopy should notice that, and reuse the "template" elements. It looks like it is not reusing the content. 
No I am not customer yet, right now I am on dev environement.
I tried to do the same with Itext7 without PDFSmapter (document.add*) but the memory consumption was even greater.

Comment: IText version is 5.5.11

Comment: That's indeed the most recent iText 5 version. When I try what you are trying, the template is reused. I am sure that the template is also reused in your case. Maybe you are creating as many font sub sets as there are pages. That would explain the extensive memory use.

Comment: The odd thing is, that the whole process produced PDF of 26MB in size. It finished right now, and that was the outcome. Would you suggest to move to IText7? I would post another question with IText7 version for the same case. I most probably missing something there as well.

Comment: Since it is mostly low-level manipulation that you need, iText 7 would probably be faster. What is the problem you experienced with iText 7? [Filling out the forms](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-4-making-pdf-interactive), freeing resources, or using [smart mode](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/WriterProperties.html#useSmartMode--)?

Comment: I have issue, that with IText7 one of form fields is not "autosizing" while with iText5 it is - using the same pdf template - font size set to 0.

Comment: Described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517814/itext7-how-to-preserve-font-autosize-property-when-filling-the-form